# Why am I having issues deploying Symfony 4 app to Heroku?

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony 4 app to Heroku and, obviously, encountering some issues with it.

I first had the "403 Forbidden" error because the document root had not been set in my Procfile.
My answer to that was, after reading other questions and answers I could find around, using any of these:

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/
web: bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 /public/
```

They all gave back different kinds of "500 Internal Server Error" pages - most of them, saying something along the lines of `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

Which lead me to think about some issue in my `public/.htaccess` file instead.

With comments removed, it looks like this:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Which is indeed weird as I have no `public/app.php` file - however, swapping that for index.php doesn't seem to fix things either.

I really don't know what else to try, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wow. 9000th.  That is impressive.  The fact that your config has app.php is a clue that you are using an older setup.  Why not use a Symfony 4 configuration?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been using Symfony for long and I came back to this project after months so my knowledge is quite basic. I'll try and take a look at the "migration" page, maybe I can find some quicker solution rather than make a new project and move stuff, thanks a lot for the hunch.

Comment: As far as I know, the current heroku php buildpack does not support Symfony 4 using default config, you should create your own .htaccess. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#web-server-settings

Comment: What's weird is that if I try to create a new Symfony 4 app and take a look in the `public` folder there's *no* .htaccess file.

Comment: Assuming you are using flex, you need to explicitly install the htaccess file.  S4 is trying to get away from delivering server specific stuff by default.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks a lot to both, I posted the solution I found as an answer in case someone else ends up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this trying to deploy a Symfony / Symfony 4 app, these are the steps I had to take to solve the issue:

- My .htaccess file was outdated and still referenced the old Symfony 3 app.php. What I had to do was delete it and get the new one via `composer require symfony/apache-pack`
- At this point, I still got a 500 Error and the Heroku logs weren't saying anything helpful. That's because Heroku requires you to log things to `php://stderr` to have them properly logged in the CLI and web interface. As such, I had to modify my `config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml` file to have the `nested` handler be like this: `path: "php://stderr"`

In my case, the second issue turned  out being I'd forgotten to run `node_modules/.bin/encore production` in my `postinstall` script - but just redirecting logging to `php://stderr` should point anyone in the right direction.

Comment: Hey are you able to provide some more detail? I'm having the same issue. For me, when I installed apache-pack, I didn't see anything in the vendor dir, and also, I'm not sure git is pushing this up to heroku since it wasn't tracked

Answer (score 3):

In my case is I did not add the route "/". Symfony load default page in local environment without that route, but in heroku we need to add it!

I show my code for your reference:

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="default")
     */
    public function ping()
    {
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'pong'
        ]);
    }
}
```